# Validator accepts submit only when re-editing field (include PHP)

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am having strange problem.

My submit button only works if I reedit any field.
If i press submit button becoming disable.
Then i need to reedit date field (any field require validation) then I can submit the form.

Note:Even reediting any field,didn't work on jsfiddle(submit button still disable).But reediting works on my project!

Here is my code
[Jsfiidle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/1k4x3f84/14/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#reportForm')
    .bootstrapValidator({
      // Only disabled elements are excluded
      // The invisible elements belonging to inactive tabs must be validated
      excluded: [':disabled'],
      feedbackIcons: {
        valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
        invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
        validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
      },
      fields: {
        reportStartDate: {
          validators: {
            notEmpty: {
              message: 'Please select Date'
            }
          }
        },
        reportEndDate: {
          validators: {
            notEmpty: {
              message: 'Please select Date'
            }
          }
        }
      }
    })
    // Called when a field is invalid
    .on('error.field.bv', function(e, data) {
      // data.element --> The field element

      var $tabPane = data.element.parents('.tab-pane'),
        tabId = $tabPane.attr('id');

      $('a[href="#' + tabId + '"][data-toggle="tab"]')
        .parent()
        .find('i')
        .removeClass('fa-check')
        .addClass('fa-times');
    })
    // Called when a field is valid
    .on('success.field.bv', function(e, data) {
      // data.bv      --> The BootstrapValidator instance
      // data.element --> The field element

      var $tabPane = data.element.parents('.tab-pane'),
        tabId = $tabPane.attr('id'),
        $icon = $('a[href="#' + tabId + '"][data-toggle="tab"]')
        .parent()
        .find('i')
        .removeClass('fa-check fa-times');

      // Check if the submit button is clicked
      if (data.bv.getSubmitButton()) {
        // Check if all fields in tab are valid
        var isValidTab = data.bv.isValidContainer($tabPane);
        $icon.addClass(isValidTab ? 'fa-check' : 'fa-times');
      }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After spending half of my day finally found solution.The problem was 'name' attribute for button.Bootstrap validation having problem to understand form submitted or not!

**When I use following way doesn't work!**

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" name="submit" value="showReport">Show Report</button>
```

With php code

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
```

---

**Solution!**

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">Show Report</button>
```

With php code

```
($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
```

Comment: You've changed the PHP also. What makes you say that the `name` attribute is the problem?

Comment: I used 'name' because  to understand form submitted or no with " if (isset($_POST['submit']))". But looks like Bootstrap having issue with this.So if I removed 'name' i can't use anymore "if (isset($_POST['submit']))" instead found better way to catch form submitted or not with "($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')".

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but realised that I had targetted the container div and not the form-tag. Might save someone some time.